# What could cause my android unity game to spontaneously restart?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

Sometimes, with no obvious trigger, our android unity game will reboot to the loading screen. We've seen it on a 2013 Nexus 7 and a new Nexus 6, but aren't sure it's device-specific.

The game is a 2d grid-based single-screen puzzle game, built with unity 4.6.1. The reboot tends to happen on entering a match, but again it's not 100%.

Theoretically what could causing an android unity game to reboot? The bug goes all the way back to the unity splash screen, which isn't something that's intentionally possible from unity's .net API, afaik.

The logcat doesn't show any thrown errors or exceptions that look suspect, but there are things like:

- strictmode policy violations, mostly in the com.google.android.apps.gmm namespace, that I don't think are to do with us
- a IllegalStateException in the com.google.android.gms namespace. We *do* use play game services for cloud save and leaderboards.
- `NetdConnector: Error handling '613 IfaceClass active (null)': java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "(null)"` but no associated callstack
- very soon after, `InputDispatcher: channel '9854a6 com.REDACTED/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9`, `Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`, which I guess is the reset, followed by WIN DEATH of the activity.

In one case there's 25%-odd memory free, which I'd expect because it's not a hugely asset-intensive game.

Any ideas of how to narrow this down?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the issue using latest Unity with Facebook SDK.

Comment: I haven't integrated facebook sdk yet, but it's on the list. maybe it's the same root cause tho.

Answer (score 0):

The restart is caused by filling all available memory and getting an out of memory error.

Unity for some reason rather than just crashing and reporting the issue will restart the app.